# simple HTML DOM tag selecting issue

Tags: php, html, dom

I have this HTML:

```
  <div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <small class="old-price">Stara cena: 1.890 RSD</small>
        <span>Ušteda: <strong>1.000 RSD</strong></span>
        <h5>890 <em>RSD</em>    
             <div class="tooltip"><p>Cene sa popustom uz gotovinsko plaćanje za online porudžbine</p></div>
        </h5>
        <span style="display:none" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RSD"></span>
        <span itemprop="price" content="890.00"></span>
    </div>
```

I'm collecting prices from  tag like this:

```
foreach($html->find('span[itemprop=price]')  as $element) {
     $niz['price'][] = $element->content;
}
```

And now i need to collect text from small tag if it exists (if it does not exist then i need empty string in an array):`<small class="old-price">Stara cena: 1.890 RSD</small>`

So i need something like this:

```
if($html->find('small[class=old-price]',0))
{
    $niz['oldprice'][] = $element->innertext;
}else{
    $niz['oldprice'][] = '';
}
```

Problem is that i get only elements from class=old-price in array and not a single empty string.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you please use code

```
foreach($html->find('small[class=old-price]')  as $element) {
    if($element->plaintext)
    {
         $niz['oldprice'][] = $element->plaintext;
    }else{
         $niz['oldprice'][] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: still no empty strings in array. This way i have only one price in all array indexes...
It seems that condition if($html->find('small[class=old-price]',0)) is always true.

Comment: now its just empty strings, like the condition if($element->find('small[class=old-price]',0)) is always false...
It has to do something with the find() function, I just dont know what it is...

Comment: Got it. I made small modifications:
foreach($html->find('div[class=price]')  as $element) {
      if($element->find('small[class=old-price]',0))
      {
         $niz['oldprice'][] = $element->find('small[class=old-price]',0)->plaintext;
      }else{
         $niz['oldprice'][] = '';
      }
  }